# Get latest object with filter in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When I request GET through DRF API, I want to return the latest object.
I tried this one in views.py:

```
class ListCreateNodeConfig(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.NodeConfig.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.NodeConfigSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(node_id=self.kwargs.get('node_pk')).latest('timestamp')
```

But it throws error: 'NodeConfig' object is not iterable

models.py

```
class NodeConfig(models.Model):  
    node_id = models.ForeignKey(Node)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    record_interval = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    lower_frequency = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    upper_frequency = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How to fix it?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: There should be a list returning to the latest method. I don't think so this is what happening in this case.

Comment: .filter() returns Queryset which is iterable according to this documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/. I cant understand why it is not working.

Comment: you should not define both `queryset` and `get_queryset `. likely not the problem here - but still... so remove the `queryset` property and replace `self.queryset...`with `models.NodeConfig.objects...`.

Comment: @ohrstrom Yes, I have tried this without queryset, but still no success:
return models.NodeConfig.objects.filter(node_id=self.kwargs.get('node_pk')).latest('timestamp')

Comment: The thing is, that code works in pure Django function (not in DRF). I can also extract the latest one in Django shell. 
Maybe problem is with my model? Do I need to add Meta class or some additional options? I added models in question

Comment: you are using DRF 'ListCreateAPIView'. this view is meant to operate with 'lists' of objects. and a queryset per definition has to be iterable.

Comment: @NursultanBolatbayev I am facing the same issue here. Did anything work for you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The porblem here ist the `latest()` method. This does not return a queryset but a single model instance. (like `get(...)`)

so use:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return self.queryset.filter(node_id=self.kwargs.get('node_pk')).order_by('-timestamp')
```

So if you want to have an endpoint for a single object you must not use DRF `List*` views/mixins.
The listviews assume you want to work with lists (=multiple objects). And so they rely on `queryset` resp. `get_queryset`. And a queryset should obviously be a queryset and not a model instance...

But there is also the `RetrieveAPIView` view included:

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView

class LatestNodeConfigView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = models.NodeConfig.objects.all()
    # add your serializer
    serializer_class = NodeConfigDetailSerializer

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.queryset.filter(node_id=kwargs.get('node_pk')).latest('timestamp')
```

Comment: Yes, I want a single model instance (single object). 
I tried that one too, but the same error. 

return models.NodeConfig.objects.filter(node_id=self.kwargs.get('node_pk')).order_by('-timestamp')[0]

Comment: The difference between latest and order_by is latest return the single object while order_by return multiple. So changing this doesn't affect the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use python slicing for return single object into queryset:

```
self
  .queryset
  .filter(node_id=self.kwargs.get('node_pk'))
  .order_by('-timestamp')[:1]
```